# Google Maps markerClusterer: how to combine Interface Renderer and GridOptions gridSize in configuration object?

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, interface, renderer, markerclusterer

I'm currently trying to implement [Google Maps JavaScript MarkerClusterer](https://github.com/googlemaps/js-markerclusterer) on a website.

I'm using [Interface Renderer](https://googlemaps.github.io/js-markerclusterer/interfaces/Renderer.html) to override a couple of default configuration parameters.

```
let renderer = {
    render: ({ count, position }) =>
        new google.maps.Marker({
            label: {
                text: String(count),
                color: "transparent",
            },
            position,
            icon: {
                url: mapOperator.imageBasePath + "pin-cluster-1.png",
            },
            // adjust zIndex to be above other markers
            zIndex: Number(google.maps.Marker.MAX_ZINDEX) + count,
        }),
};

let config = { map, markers, renderer };
let cluster = new markerClusterer.MarkerClusterer(config);
```

Please note that I'm adding markerClusterer plugin via unpkg. So I must declare the cluster this way: `let cluster = new markerClusterer.MarkerClusterer(config);` ([as stated in the "Install" section of the official documentation](https://github.com/googlemaps/js-markerclusterer#install)) (see last line of my above code bit).

This code works great, but I'd also like to override [gridSize property from Interface GridOptions](https://googlemaps.github.io/js-markerclusterer/interfaces/GridOptions.html#gridSize) in order (well, I hope... I'm not even sure this option will give me what I expect; I'm not english native and given description is not totally clear to me...) to get bigger clusters and less individual markers on my map.

I'm struggling for a couple of reasons:

- I'm not familiar with they way the code has to be set up,
- the documentation is EMPTY and there's NO supplied example code on how to achieve what I want,
- can't find any help on stack overflow, tutorials (blogs, social networks, ...). Really, all I could find were 100k of obsolete ways to do it but that doesn't work when you use Interface Renderer. Here's an example:

```
var markerClusterer = new MarkerClusterer(map, markers, {
    gridSize: 10,
    maxZoom: 9, // maxZoom set when clustering will stop
    imagePath: 'https://cdn.rawgit.com/googlemaps/js-marker-clusterer/gh-pages/images/m'
});
```

So I tried several things but nothing is working:

```
let config = { map, markers, renderer, GridOptions: { gridSize: 10 } };
```

```
let renderer = {
    render: ({ count, position }) =>
        new google.maps.Marker({
            label: {
                text: String(count),
                color: "transparent",
            },
            position,
            icon: {
                url: mapOperator.imageBasePath + "pin-cluster-1.png",
            },
            // adjust zIndex to be above other markers
            zIndex: Number(google.maps.Marker.MAX_ZINDEX) + count,
            gridSize: 10,
        }),
};
```

```
let renderer = {
    render: ({ count, position }) =>
        new google.maps.Marker({
            label: {
                text: String(count),
                color: "transparent",
            },
            position,
            icon: {
                url: mapOperator.imageBasePath + "pin-cluster-1.png",
            },
            // adjust zIndex to be above other markers
            zIndex: Number(google.maps.Marker.MAX_ZINDEX) + count,
        }),
    
    GridOptions: ({ gridSize = 10 }),
    // gridSize: 10,
};
```

Can anyone help me? Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally:

```
let renderer = {
    render: ({ count, position }) =>
        new google.maps.Marker({
            label: {
                text: String(count),
                color: "transparent",
            },
            position,
            icon: {
                url: mapOperator.imageBasePath + "pin-cluster-1.png",
            },
            // adjust zIndex to be above other markers
            zIndex: Number(google.maps.Marker.MAX_ZINDEX) + count,
        }),
};
let algorithm = new markerClusterer.GridAlgorithm({gridSize: 60});

let config = { map, markers, renderer, algorithm };
let cluster = new markerClusterer.MarkerClusterer(config);
```

And also, Yes, gridSize property does generate bigger clusters and less individual markers on map if you increase its value (default: 40).

Answer (score 0):

i think it's best to use SuperClusterAlgorithm instead of GridAlgorithm, the Gridalgorithm makes my map lag a lot and zooming has poor performance.

```
const algorithm = new markerClusterer.SuperClusterAlgorithm({ maxZoom: 12, radius: 80});
```

what i didn't discovered yet is how to set the other options:

reference: https://github.com/googlemaps/js-markerclusterer/blob/68f10c5b0a7fe884cb927ff2b320fe78159a4f93/src/algorithms/supercluster.ts

```
constructor({ maxZoom, radius = 60, ...options }: SuperClusterOptions) {
super({ maxZoom });

this.superCluster = new SuperCluster({
  maxZoom: this.maxZoom,
  radius,
  ...options,
});
```

minPoints for example... i can't make it work.

```
new markerClusterer.SuperClusterAlgorithm({minPoints: 100})
```