# How to modify google maps clustering algorithm / options

Tags: google-maps

I have 500+ markers on my javascript google map and working on adding clustering.
Having issues setting some simple options and custom images using
[js-markerclusterer](https://github.com/googlemaps/js-markerclusterer) Public Github library.
Following this [Google developer guide](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/marker-clustering#cdn) guide and adding the library using CDN

I expected to set my options like this:

```
const clusterOptions = {
imagePath: "<imagepath>",
gridSize: 30,
zoomOnClick: false,
maxZoom: 10,
};

const markerCluster = new markerClusterer.MarkerClusterer({ map, markers, clusterOptions});
```

This has no effect on the clusters.
What is the correct way of setting cluster options?

Here is a bigger snippet of my code:

```
function initMap() {
    // Create the map.
        var lastWindow = null;
        var markers = new Array();
        const map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
            zoom: 16,
            keyboardShortcuts: false,
            center: { lat: 40.748817, lng: -73.985428 },
            disableDefaultUI: true,
            gestureHandling: "greedy",
            ClickableIcons: false,
            styles: mapStyle,
            restriction: {
                latLngBounds: NEW_YORK_BOUNDS,
                strictBounds: true
                    },
            
        });

        const markers_map = {{markers_map | tojson | safe}};
        const infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

        // Create markers.
        for (let i = 0; i < markers_map.length; i++) {
            const currMarker = markers_map[i];

            const marker = new google.maps.Marker({
              position: {lat: currMarker.lat, lng: currMarker.lng},
              map,
              animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
              icon: currMarker.icon
            });

  
              


            marker.addListener("click", () => {
              if (lastWindow) {lastWindow.close()};
              lastWindow = infowindow;
              const _id = currMarker._id;
              const name = currMarker.name;
              const url_link = currMarker.url_link;
              const address = currMarker.address;
              const neighborhood = currMarker.neighborhood;
              const from_day = currMarker.from_day;
              const to_day = currMarker.to_day;
              const from_hours = currMarker.from_hours;
              const to_hours = currMarker.to_hours;
              const content = `
              <div class=infowindow>
                  <div class=infowindow__imagecontainer>
                      <img class=infowindow__image src=${url_link} alt=HappyHour img>
                  </div>
                  <div class=infowindow__content onclick=nextpage()>
                      <h2 class=markers__name>${name}</h2><p class=markers__neighborhood>In ${neighborhood}</p>
                      <div class=markers__section>
                          <p class=markers__address>${address}</p>
                          {{ map("container__map") }}
                      </div>
                      <div class=infowindow__output>
                          <div class=output__details>${from_day}</div>
                          <div class=output__details>${to_day}</div>
                          <div class=output__details>${from_hours}</div>
                          <div class=output__details>${to_hours}</div>
                      </div>
                      <div class=infowindow__next>
                              {{ click("container__click") }}
                          <p>Click to see more</p>
                      </div>
                  <div>
                      <form name=infowindow--form id=next action=/location/${_id}></form>
              </div>
          `   ;
              
              infowindow.open({
                anchor: marker,
                map,
                shouldFocus: false,
              });

              infowindow.setContent(content)
              
            });

            markers.push(marker);
            
            map.addListener('click', () => {
            infowindow.close();
          });

            
        }   

        const clusterOptions = {
        imagePath: "<imagepath>",
        gridSize: 30,
        zoomOnClick: false,
        maxZoom: 10,
        };

        const markerCluster = new markerClusterer.MarkerClusterer({ map, markers, clusterOptions});
```

Comment: Related, possible duplicate question: [Google Maps markerClusterer: how to combine Interface Renderer and GridOptions gridSize in configuration object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73286425/google-maps-markerclusterer-how-to-combine-interface-renderer-and-gridoptions-g)