# google maps MarkerClusterer how to personalize the renderer

Tags: javascript, google-maps, markerclusterer

I'm using [MarkerClusterer](https://googlemaps.github.io/js-markerclusterer/) with google maps api, I'm trying to change the behavior of the markers with the renderer inerface, as they explain in the doc : https://googlemaps.github.io/js-markerclusterer

problem is, I don't understand the doc... it says that the MarkerClusterer class can accept parameters :

```
{
    algorithm?: Algorithm;
    map?: google.maps.Map;
    markers?: google.maps.Marker[];
    renderer?: Renderer;
    onClusterClick?: onClusterClickHandler;
}
```

and indeed I can see it in the source code : https://github.com/googlemaps/js-markerclusterer/blob/1ee6469fa3c62a30c39cf509b379847741a7ebb9/src/markerclusterer.ts

and I can see here the implementation of DefaultRenderer, the default value for the renderer parameter : https://github.com/googlemaps/js-markerclusterer/blob/1ee6469fa3c62a30c39cf509b379847741a7ebb9/src/renderer.ts

so in my code, I thought I should create an object with a method called `render` that returns a `new google.maps.Marker`. I tried lots of different variations, I show you one there, in which I took the source code with few modifications (colors of markerclusters), I don't know what I should actually do to make it works :

```js
function init_map() {
  let map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("ljdp_map"), { zoom: 2, center: {lat:46.227638, lng:2.213749} });
  let markers = [];
  for (ev of events)   // events is defined outside this function
    markers.push( new google.maps.Marker({ position: ev.coordinates, map: map }) );

  // so, this is where I try to modify the cluster appearance, without luck
  // maybe "my_renderer" need to be a class inheriting from DefaultRenderer ?
  //   class my_renderer extends markerClusterer.DefaultRenderer {
  // it didn't work
  let my_renderer = {
    render({ count, position }, stats) {
      const svg = window.btoa(`
        <svg fill="#00ff00" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 240 240">
          <circle cx="120" cy="120" opacity=".6" r="70" /></svg>`);
      return new google.maps.Marker({
        position,
        icon: {
          url: `data:image/svg+xml;base64,${svg}`,
          scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(45, 45),
        },
        title: `Cluster of ${count} markers`,
        zIndex: Number(google.maps.Marker.MAX_ZINDEX) + count,
      });
    }
  }
  // since the render argument is the fourth, after an algorithm argument, in the constructor,
  // maybe I need to create an algorithm object to place the renderer at the right position ?
  //   let algorithm = new markerClusterer.SuperClusterAlgorithm({});
  //   new markerClusterer.MarkerClusterer({ map, markers, algorithm, my_renderer });
  // it didn't work

  new markerClusterer.MarkerClusterer({ map, markers, my_renderer });
}
```

the init function is called with :

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=API_KEY&callback=ini_map"></script>
```

and the marker clustering library is added by this script :

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@googlemaps/markerclusterer/dist/index.min.js"></script>
```

and the output is as if I didn't add `my_renderer`, cluster are not personalized. I don't know if I'm on the right way but making mistakes, or if it's not the way intended to modify the clusters ?

Comment: related question: [Google Maps markerClusterer: how to combine Interface Renderer and GridOptions gridSize in configuration object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73286425/google-maps-markerclusterer-how-to-combine-interface-renderer-and-gridoptions-g)

Answer (score 2):

so, looking at this other SO post : [Google Maps markerClusterer: how to combine Interface Renderer and GridOptions gridSize in configuration object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73286425/google-maps-markerclusterer-how-to-combine-interface-renderer-and-gridoptions-g)

I found what didn't work : the parameter name has to be exactly `renderer` and not `my_renderer` (that explains why the order in parameters didn't matters)

but I don't know why, maybe it's a typescript thing (I don't know typescript yet) ? I don't see it when I look at [the source code](https://github.com/googlemaps/js-markerclusterer/blob/1ee6469fa3c62a30c39cf509b379847741a7ebb9/src/markerclusterer.ts), but there are lots of things I don't understand there anyway

the working code is the same, except for the object name :

```js
function init_map() {
  let map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("ljdp_map"), { zoom: 2, center: {lat:46.227638, lng:2.213749} });
  let markers = [];
  for (ev of events)   // events is defined outside this function
    markers.push( new google.maps.Marker({ position: ev.coordinates, map: map }) );

  // this is where the error was : the object has to be named exactly 'renderer'
  let renderer = {
    render({ count, position }, stats) {
      const svg = window.btoa(`
        <svg fill="#00ff00" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 240 240">
          <circle cx="120" cy="120" opacity=".6" r="70" /></svg>`);
      return new google.maps.Marker({
        position,
        icon: {
          url: `data:image/svg+xml;base64,${svg}`,
          scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(45, 45),
        },
        title: `Cluster of ${count} markers`,
        zIndex: Number(google.maps.Marker.MAX_ZINDEX) + count,
      });
    }
  }

  new markerClusterer.MarkerClusterer({ map, markers, renderer });
}
```

I don't know why :/

(I'll mark my answer as the solution for the moment, since it works, even though I don't have the explanation why)

Comment: You could name it `const my_renderer = { render: () => {}}`, but in this case, you should use it the following way: `new markerClusterer.MarkerClusterer({ map, markers, renderer: my_renderer })`;